# Why does the definition of 2-cycle as $\ker\partial_2$ work so magically?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

I am curious about why the definition of $\ker\partial_2$ as 2-cycles (a 2-dimensional hole or void) works so well. It seems like a mystery to me. (I am referring to the simplicial complex case.)

For $n=1$, I can intuitvely understand.  For instance, for the loop connecting the vertices $v_0,v_1,v_2$, we have $\partial_1[v_0,v_1]=v_1-v_0$, $\partial_1[v_1,v_2]=v_2-v_1$ and $\partial[v_2,v_0]=v_0-v_2$. So adding them up produces a "telescoping sum" effect, which corresponds to "closing the loop":

$$v_1-v_0+v_2-v_1+v_0-v_2=0$$

For $n=2$, it seems like a mystery to me. Consider the tetrahedron (3 simplex with vertices $v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3$). There are 4 faces:

$$\partial_2[v_0,v_1,v_2]=[v_1,v_2]-[v_0,v_2]+[v_0,v_1]$$
$$\partial_2[v_0,v_1,v_3]=[v_1,v_3]-[v_0,v_3]+[v_0,v_1]$$
$$\partial_2[v_0,v_2,v_3]=[v_2,v_3]-[v_0,v_3]+[v_0,v_2]$$
$$\partial_2[v_1,v_2,v_3]=[v_2,v_3]-[v_1,v_3]+[v_1,v_2]$$

**Question:** The mystery to me is why is it so nice that:

$$\partial_2[v_0,v_1,v_2]-\partial_2[v_0,v_1,v_3]+\partial_2[v_0,v_2,v_3]-\partial_2[v_1,v_2,v_3]=0$$, which corresponds to the 4 faces enclosing a 2-dimensional hole? What is the mathematics behind it?

I roughly know that this means that the $\partial_2[v_0,v_1,v_2],\dots, \partial_2[v_1,v_2,v_3]$ are "linearly dependent" therefore they have a linear combination that makes zero. However this explanation is not satisfying enough for me.

**Further question:** This brings me to ask the next question, how about for $n\geq 3$? How are we so sure that $\ker\partial_n$ is a $n$-dimensional hole?

Thanks.

Comment: Ignore signs (signs are about orientations; worry about that after you understand the unoriented situation). The equation says that you can match up faces pairwise of your simplices to assemble them into a simplicial complex $M$, equipped with a map $f: M \to X$ ($X$ your space) with the following property: every $(n-1)$-simplex of $M$ is contained in exactly two $n$-simplices. This says that away from the $(n-2)$-skeleton, $M$ is a *manifold*, and we have a map from such a "pseudomanifold" into $X$. Such a map is a boundary if and only if there is...

Comment: an $(n+1)$-dimensional "pseudomanifold with boundary" ($(n-1)$-simplices are contained in either one or two $n$-simplices) $W$ and a map $\bar f: W \to X$ with $\partial W = M$ and $\bar f\big|_{M} = f$. So a "hole" is detected by a pseudomanifold, and to say that it's really a hole means that it can't be "filled in" by any other pseudomanifolds. The reason for the pseudo- could philosophically be traced back to the fact that not every manifold $M$ is the boundary of another manifold, but every pseudomanifold is by design the boundary of a pseudomanifold - the cone $C(M)$!

Comment: If you want to see this construction of a map-from-a-pseudomanifold from a chain, Hatcher does this for 2-dimensional chains in the process of proving $\pi_1^{ab} = H_1$, IIRC.